# How to resolve "arguments are different" error - unit testing

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I wanted to write unit test for my **addTask** method with mockito. 
Here is the class that contains this method.

```
package controller;

import model.Task;
import model.User;
import repository.TaskActions;
import repository.UserActions;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

public class ToDoEngine {
private TaskActions taskActions;
private UserActions userActions;
private User connectedUser;

public ToDoEngine(UserActions userStorage, TaskActions taskStorage) {
    this.taskActions = taskStorage;
    this.userActions = userStorage;
}

public boolean signIn(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    connectedUser = new User(username, password);
    if (!userActions.signIn(connectedUser)) {
        return false;
    }
    connectedUser.setID(retrieveConnectedUserID(connectedUser));
    return true;
}

private int retrieveConnectedUserID(User connectedUser) throws SQLException {
    return userActions.retrieveUserID(connectedUser);
}

public void addTask(String taskName) throws SQLException {
    taskActions.addTask(new Task(taskName), connectedUser);
}

}
```

Here are my attempts. Unfortunately, I've got error. Below, I am gonna present you stacktrace:

```
package controller;

import model.Task;
import model.User;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import repository.TaskActions;
import repository.UserActions;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class ToDoEngineTest {

@Mock
TaskActions taskActionsMock;
@Mock
UserActions userActionsMock;
private ToDoEngine toDoEngine;


@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    toDoEngine = new ToDoEngine(userActionsMock, taskActionsMock);
}

@Test
public void addTask() throws SQLException {
    Task taskName = new Task("wash");
    User user = new User("admin","123");
    toDoEngine.addTask("wash");
    verify(taskActionsMock).addTask(taskName,user);
}
}
```

**stacktrace**:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
taskActionsMock.addTask(
    Task(taskName=wash),
    model.User@1b71f500
);
-> at controller.ToDoEngineTest.addTask(ToDoEngineTest.java:68)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
taskActionsMock.addTask(
    Task(taskName=wash),
    null
);
-> at controller.ToDoEngine.addTask(ToDoEngine.java:40)

Comparison Failure:  <Click to see difference>

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
taskActionsMock.addTask(
    Task(taskName=wash),
    model.User@1b71f500
);
-> at controller.ToDoEngineTest.addTask(ToDoEngineTest.java:68)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
taskActionsMock.addTask(
    Task(taskName=wash),
    null
);
-> at controller.ToDoEngine.addTask(ToDoEngine.java:40)
at controller.ToDoEngineTest.addTask(ToDoEngineTest.java:68)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
...
```

User and Task class contains hashCode and Equals method.

**Task**

```
package model;

import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Task {
private String taskName;
}
```

**User**:

```
package model;

import lombok.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode

public class User {

private final String name;
private final String password;
private int ID;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test case you are attempting to verify a call onto this method:

```
public void addTask(String taskName) throws SQLException {
    taskActions.addTask(new Task(taskName), connectedUser);
}
```

With this:

```
User user = new User("admin","123");
...
verify(taskActionsMock).addTask(taskName,user);
```

The failure message ...

```
Actual invocation has different arguments:
taskActionsMock.addTask(
    Task(taskName=wash),
    null
);
```

... tells us that the value of `connectedUser` in the test call is `null`.

Looking at your code the `connectedUser` member of `ToDoEngine` is populated by a call to the `signIn()` method but your test case is not invoking that method and hence `connectedUser` is null when `addTask` is invoked by your test.

So, if you don't need/want to test that the correct user is supplied to `addTask` then just change your verify call to:  `verify(taskActionsMock).addTask(taskName,null)`

However, that feels like a sidestep so instead you should ensure that `connectedUser` is not null and is the value you supplied to the verify call in your test case.

Comment: Well...I added this line of code, nothing removed:  `toDoEngine.signIn("admin","123");`  . Test passed, but Im not sure if I did in right way. Do I need `User user = new User("admin","123");` line now? Im asking, because I don't understand, in `signIn`method I create new object of user, and then I create another object of user.

Comment: Ok, so your changes addressed this point: "you should ensure that connectedUser is not null and is the value you supplied to the verify call in your test case" and hence your test passed. That's valid and I don't think you need any more changes to the `addTask()` test. You could verify the behaviour within `signIn` by setting an expectation on `userActionsMock.signIn()` (when that returns true then connectedUser will have an id, otherwise not) but that's a separate test.

Comment: Yeah.But my question is, in `signIn` method I create new object of user (connectedUser) and after that I create another object of user that I pass here `verify(taskActionsMock).addTask(taskName,user);`. How do we know that this is the same object of `connectedUser`?

Comment: It's not the same object but you are not asserting that it is the **same** object, instead you are asserting (by invoking `verify()`) that the two different instances of user are equal. So your test expects that a user having name=admin and password=123 will be passed to `addTask` and this is what your code does so therefore the test passes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `verify` method specifies that you expect `addTask` to be called with specific `taskName` and `user` objects.

```
verify(taskActionsMock).addTask(taskName,user);
```

But since your connected user is `null` this expectation fails.
If you do not care about the connected user you can use matchers to tell Mockito to ignore its actual value. E.G.

```
verify(taskActionsMock).addTask(ArgumentMatchers.eq(taskName), ArgumentMatchers.any());
```

Or if you do care about the user just setup your ToDoEngine to have connected user.